# Web application that deals with files -upload download

Tags: java, web-applications

I have an existing swing desktop application that I wish to convert to a web application. The first thing that is stopping from doing so is that the desktop application deals with writing and reading from PDF files. Also the user fills up the PDF forms which needs  to be read by the application.

Now a typical use case in the desktop application is like, the user logs in opens a PDF form and fills it up. The swing application manages where the file is stored so it goes to the file and reads the form, extracts the data and stores the data in the db. The user might not fill up the form all in one go. He might save it come back to it later and continue.

All of this needs to be done by the web app now. My problem is I don't want the user to download and upload the form  multiple times to the server. That would eat the bandwidth and also asking the use to save the file locally and upload it back once he completes filling the form doesn't appeal to me since the desktop application nicely used to manage the location of these files as well.

Would I need to implement something like a dropbox kind of thing? A small deamon running  continuously to check what file has been updated and upload it to the server? That would be difficult since at the server I wouldn't know if the file was latest or not. Is there anything like this that someone might have done before?

Answer (score 5):

I have anther suggestion: why don't you show the user a form with the same fields and transfer them to the PDF after the user submits. This way the Pdf does not leave the server and you transmit just the minimal amount of data.

Answer (score 3):

Switching to a web-version of the application may force you to re-think some of the way you are doing things.  Certainly browsers are intentionally limited in their access to the local file system which introduces a major hurdle for your current mode of operation.

Even if you could display the PDF within a browser, detect the completion of edits and send this back to the server from within browser code (which is probably possible), you'll be subject to different browsers doing different (strange) things with whatever pdf plugin is installed.

As Vitaliy mentioned already, switching being able to populate a (web) form in the browser means that whole download upload problem goes away.  But then you have to take what the user has done in a web page and pump that into a PDF somehow.  If you don't HAVE to start with a PDF, but could collect the data and produce a PDF at the end then you might have more options.  For example you could use iText to create a PDF directly if you don't have too many styles of document to work with.  You could use something like Docmosis which you can give templates to and get it to populate and render PDFs later.  With the Docmosis option you can also ask Docmosis for the list of fields in the template so could build a web form based on the selected template, let the user fill it in, then push that data to Docmosis to produce the file.

Hopefully there's some options there that are useful to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would be difficult to do. These pdfs are have a huge number of fields. They are not owned by me. They are XFA forms with Digital signatures and attachments and stuff. Anyway, the problem is not just limited to the pdf forms. There are word documents, excel and any other document a user wants to work with. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question earlier..

Answer (score 0):

Adobe [documents how to do this here](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-forms-form-data-web.html).  Never underestimate the power of design-by-google.  I know this can be made to work because I've used PDF forms on line.

Comment: The PDF forms are not the simple FDF exported data but rather XFA http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html which are a lot more complex. I really dont want to have a form field on my html page replacing every field in the form. That's why the form is there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar issue a few years ago, although I wasn't dealing with signed forms.  The signature definitely makes it a little more difficult.  However, I was able to use iText to create a PDF form with fields, and only submit the field data back to the server.  Offhand, I unfortunately do not remember exactly what/how we did it, but can confirm it is doable (with limitations/caveats).  Ex: User had to have PDF reader plugin installed &  User was forced to d/l the pdf every time.

Basically what I did was use iText to create an FDF from a PDF (with form existing form fields).  The submit button in the FDF actually submits the form data to a URL of your choosing (not unlike an HTML form).  Once you have that data, I believe I merged the form fields (from the FDF) with the PDF on the server side using iText.

Once you use the server to maintain all the form data, the synchronization/locking process you use to ensure that a single user is updating the latest and greatest form data is up to you.

Your comment under jowierun indicates that you want to deal with word/excel/etc docs as well, so I am not entirely sure I am understanding your needs.  Your initial post discussed the needs to fill out PDF forms locally, but afterwards it sounds like you are looking for a file-sharing system instead.

Can you please clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hey Eric, you are right it would be a file sharing system. But I am more concerned with the PDF forms. My server will read from/ write to these PDF forms. The issue is, when the user completes filling up the form and I need to read the data from the form in the server, I need to know that the form is the latest form. I dont want to ask my user to go through the download-fill up-upload cycle which is quite tedious. Instead if the cycle becomes download-fill up and then the server knows that it needs to get the form from the user's system before it proceeds, that would be ideal

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a little extra background on what I did.  But your requirement doesn't make a lot of sense.  You want to store the saved PDF on the client, and have your server retrieve the PDF from the client when you need it?  It almost sounds as a P2P system now.  What if the client is offline?  Or the client's HD crashes, etc?  And the upload process would only be uploading the field data, so not any more tedious than clicking on "save".

Comment: Not p2p, rather I was thinking a dropbox like deamon could keep running on the background of the client. This will keep checking if any downloaded file has been modified, if so, it will upload it to the server. And I cant ask the user to type form fields and merge it with the PDF, because it is tedious to so as there are over a 100 forms. These forms are not FDF but rather XFA forms. I can make the deamon communicate with the server so, I would know if the deamon was not running when the client logs on.

Comment: I'm just not following / understanding your problems.  I am not sure why it is more tedious to click on a submit/save button which uploads form data to the web vs clicking save to save to your HD.  I do know know the XFA specification, but I presume there must be something similar which allows you to submit form data to the web.